# Livewire Calendar: How to add Next Month and Previous Month

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

In our application, we have activities module. I implemented the livewire calendar in our application but having a hard time displaying the next & previous month

I used the cdn of tailwindcss.

**Dashboard View**

```
<div>
<!-- <livewire:appointments-calendar/> -->
<livewire:appointments-grid
    week-starts-at="0"
    before-calendar-view="livewire/members-portal\members-dashboard\before-month"

/>
```

**Before Month View File**

```
<h2 class="">{{ $this->startsAt->format('M Y') }} </h2>
```

**Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\MembersPortal\MembersDashboard;

use Livewire\Component;
use Asantibanez\LivewireCalendar\LivewireCalendar;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class MembersDashboard extends LivewireCalendar
{
    public function events() : Collection
    {
        // must return a Laravel collection
        return collect([
                [
                    'id' => 1,
                    'title' => 'Breakfast',
                    'description' => 'Pancakes! ',
                    'date' => Carbon::today(),
                ],
                [
                    'id' => 2,
                    'title' => 'Meeting with Pamela',
                    'description' => 'Work stuff',
                    'date' => Carbon::tomorrow(),
                ],
            ]);
    }
}
```

Question: How do I display the next & previous month using livewire calendar?

Answer (score 1):

If what you're asking is how to navigate to the next and previous months, then I suggest reading the readme for that package,

> The component has 3 public methods that can help navigate forward and backward through months:
>
> `goToPreviousMonth`
> `goToNextMonth`
> `goToCurrentMonth`

This means that you can add a `wire:click` to these, since your component extends that package's component.

```html
<h2 class="">{{ $this->startsAt->format('M Y') }} </h2>
<button wire:click="goToPreviousMonth">Previous</button>
<button wire:click="goToCurrentMonth">Current</button>
<button wire:click="goToNextMonth">Next</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

With Livewire, I think you can declare in your class 2 properties to store the month and year display currently. After that, you can create two buttons previous and next month.

In `Calendar.php`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\MembersPortal\MembersDashboard;

use Livewire\Component;
use Asantibanez\LivewireCalendar\LivewireCalendar;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class MembersDashboard extends LivewireCalendar
{
    public $currentMonth = 1;
    public $currentYear  = 2022;

    public function nextMonth()
    {
        // Set the month/year and call events() to update appointment list
    }

    public function previousMonth()
    {
        // Set the month/year and call events() to update appointment list
    }

    public function events() : Collection
    {
        $collect = Model::query()->get();

        return collect([...]);
    }
    ...
}
```